# Current state of BufferedImage vs VolatileImage

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage

What is the current best practices when it comes to implementing fast image drawing to a window? I'm talking about something very bare-bones, say a single JFrame with a 2-buffer buffer strategy. What is the (current) fastest way to do this?

I've read all over the place that VolatileImage is hardware accelerated whereas BufferedImage is managed, except maybe not anymore because with each new update (+ the release of Java 7) this may no longer be the case as Java accelerates more and more of BufferedImage, etc., etc.

So (in general) what would be your suggestions on implementing fast image drawing with these conditions:

- Java 6u33+ or Java 7+
- Either one image to cover the whole JFrame or multiple small images
- Image transparency may or may not be enabled but must be supported easily enough
- If it helps think of a game-loop like setup where active rendering is used

Before anyone asks I have attempted to benchmark these two and I see little to no difference on my hardware. I have heard however that this might be hardware dependent as well so I'm really just looking for modern best practices.

Comment: There really is hardly any difference between BufferedImage and VolatileImage, as you said, BufferedImage is virtually hardware accelerated these days. Also, i read something about VolatileImage being slower in fullscreen mode but i'm guessing that was probably hardware dependant.

Comment: Right. Is there any official documentation or benchmarks that would help in proving this?

Answer (score 2):

*From my moved thread "BufferedImage vs VolatileImage - PERFORMANCE COMPARISON" (edited and improved):*

### Introduction

I recently found a [post on JavaGaming.org](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/awesome-speeds-with-volatileimage/27391/view.html) about the VolatileImage and it's awesome performance in comparison to BufferedImage. I tried it myself in one of mine projects and it's advantage seemed obvious!
But nitpicky as I am, I wanted to see results in form of numbers, and that's what I came up with:

---

### Benchmarking

I decided to create a little program that gives me some benchmark results to compare the two image types in different conditions.

**The Program:** The benchmark methodology is easy. A 2K (2560x1440) test image get's downscaled to HD (1280x720) and then drawn onto a BufferedImage or a VolatileImage (I use a BufferedImage to store the test image as tests showed that it made no difference what image type I use to store it). Then there are two variants:
  **1st** As the test image get's drawn to either the Buffered- or the VolatileImage the Buffered- or the VolatileImage get drawn to the frame's JPanel in the same loop run.
  **2nd** The test image get's drawn n-times on the Volatile- or BufferedImage before they get drawn to the JPanel. The program records how long the execution of both tests (1st BufferedImage, 2nd VolatileImage) takes and prints it out in the console. I also tested how the results would be if you use the same test picture with an alpha channel (transparency) since I often saw somebody claiming VolatileImage's would have problems with them.

**The Results:** I ran the program on a Mac Minit (late 2012) with an Intel i5 Dual Core at 2.5Ghz. The used Java version was v8_112, executed via Eclipse. Here are my results:

```
Test-methodology 1 - no transparency:
  Num of Repeats:  BufferedImage:  VolatileImage:
   200              3.280 Seconds    0.784 Seconds
   500              8.230 Seconds    1.818 Seconds
   1000             16.030 Seconds   3.666 Seconds

Test-methodology 1 - transparancy:
  Num of Repeats:  BufferedImage:  VolatileImage:
   200              4.166 Seconds   0.806 Seconds
   500              10.636 Seconds  1.793 Seconds
   1000             20.565 Seconds  3.514 Seconds

Test-methodology 2 - no transparancy:
  Num of Repeats:  BufferedImage:  VolatileImage:
   200              1.165 Seconds   0.093 Seconds
   500              2.862 Seconds   0.104 Seconds
   1000             5.770 Seconds   0.112 Seconds

Test-methodology 2 - transparancy:
  Num of Repeats:  BufferedImage:  VolatileImage:
   200              2.389 Seconds   0.120 Seconds
   500              5.986 Seconds   0.128 Seconds
   1000             11.902 Seconds  0.134 Seconds
```

---

### Conclusion

Of course, a lot about performance depends on how the images are implemented and used. In my case as buffers that allow me to do things like fading with the whole image. But still, you can find some significant down- and upsides to both image types:

Generally, the VolatileImage seems much faster (4 to 6 times) in the test than the BufferedImage. And in got similar results in a non-synthetic test when I used the same implementation for a tiny game. But in my testing, I came along a way of implementation (sadly, I cannot reconstruct it) that showed me, that a VolatileImage isn't the way to always go (yes it was slower than it's rival in this case).

Looking at transparency, both image types scaled evenly, but the VolatileImage didn't seem to lose far as much speed as the BufferedImage though adding an alpha channel.

What I want to mention: In my tests with a low number of loop runs (1-10), I discovered, that the BufferedImage was much faster in drawing a single frame. Especially when a transparent image was rendered. A single frame took the BufferedImage about 0.03 second, the VolatileImage needed 0.035. The gap grew even bigger when using around 3 to 6 loop-runs. Only at more than 8 to 10 the VolatileImage took the field and got better as bigger the amount of loop-runs grew...

*I'd like to extend this conclusion with your opinions (backed up by tests) and also want to know which implementations of those two images you came up and how they varied there.*

Personally, I will use VolatileImage's for rendering in future. BufferedImage's will be my daily driver for storing images that then get drawn in my render loop. Mainly, because I find them easier to handle with (there's a way to convert BIs to VIs but that's a story for another time). I also look forward to Java 9, that had been announced for this December but seems to be delayed, and will run my tests again.

---

### Source

I uploaded my [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/DesertCoockie/Benchmark). You can look at it and if you want, pull it and try it yourself!

Comment: I forked your benchmark and very nearly rewrote it to reflect what I consider to be a more "normal" use case.  In my use case, I don't perform N loops of writing to the buffer before writing to the screen - I perform N loops of writing M things to the buffer AND writing to the screen.  With the updated tests, BufferedImage is very nearly as performant as VolatileImage, and can actually be MORE performant if you have to reallocate the VolatileImage often.

Here's my [fork on GitHub](https://github.com/ideastorm/Benchmark)

Comment: Very interesting. I recently noticed the same thing when retrying my benchmark on a Windows machine. Maybe Mac has a different implementation of VolatileImage? Can't figure out why Mac and Windows react that differently.

Comment: BTW: Drawing n times to an image before rendering it to a screen is very realistic! Maybe not rendering the same image to it every time but you often have to use an image as a back buffer and draw a lot of textures to it, before rendering it to the screen!

Comment: @Phil Hayward I ran your GitHub code (could you enable 'issues' there maybe?) and I am seeing insane performance numbers (see https://code.botcompany.de/1033787). VolatileImage gives around 40,000 fps! Will have to check if this is actually correct. I've never used VolatileImage before.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any official documentation or benchmarks that would help in proving this?

Not that I'm aware of.  However, you could probably modify this Java 2D benchmark to compare the two approaches:    http://www.randelshofer.ch/oop/graphics/index.html

(Standard caveats about Java benchmarking apply ...)